# iText add image to pdf - setAbsolutePosition

Tags: java, image, itext

I am trying to add image to pdf using iText and set the image position at the end of the last `element` on the pdf(so there will be no empty rows on the page), following [iText-image-to-pdf](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-3), I could not find the right settings in `img.setAbsolutePosition` to do so.

Can I do that with `iText` or there is another way to find out where pdf `Page` ends?

Comment: See this answer with more info on text margins so you can get an X and Y location and use them with `setAbsolutePosition`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13029840/1270000

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by *"the end of the last element"*? Do you only thunk of text elements? What about footers? What if the bottom-most element is not drawn horizontally, shall the image also be somewhat rotated? What about invisible elements? Etc. etc.

Comment: There are only text elements on the page, no footers, horizontal or hidden ones, simple page with content that ends in the middle.